# Работа с позициями в списке

Tags: java, android

У меня фигурирует pos таки образом, что к примеру в коде

```
if (controlList.get(pos).getImageUploads().size() > 9) {
```

я добавляю в список не больше 10 элементов.
Но есть загвоздка, хочу первую позицию всегда перенести вправо. 
Это ведь возможно?

Comment: Что значит «первую позицию всегда перенести вправо»?

Comment: Ну значение pos это у меня первый элемент(картинка) по нажатию на которую я добавляю элементы. И я хочу чтобы эта позиция передвигалась вправо. То есть мы добавляем картинку и она становится на место моей pos, а pos в свою очередь передвигалась вправо.

Comment: Я все равно ничего не понял. Попробуйте переформулировать свой вопрос. Начните с того, что в приведенном фрагменте кода Вы ничего не добавляете (а говорите, что добавляете).

Comment: просто добавляйте новую картинку/или что там по индексу 0

Comment: советую заюзать что то что реализует интерфейс Queue

Comment: Автор хочет реализовать сетку? Вправо вроде только для сетки. Тоесть вот допустим сетка пуста. Только кнопка с плюсом. При нажатии на неё добавляется картинка и получается сетка теперь состоит иж картинки в верхнем левом углу и той же кнопкой справа от нее

Answer (score 0):

При работе со списками никогда не забывайте, что позиции элементов начинаются с нуля. Т.е. для того, чтобы вызвать **первый** элемент списка, вы должны обратиться так: `Object o = yourList.get(0);`

Answer (score 0):

возможно, если все правильно понял, то вот так:

```
public void addToFirst(YourType yourItem) {

    if (yourList.isEmpty()){
        yourList.add(yourItem);
    } else {
        yourList.add(0, yourItem);
    }
}
```